# Problems rendering controller with twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm calling the controller from Twig to the following expression:

```
 {{ render(controller("Bundle:Holidays:HolidaysPerMonth", { 'id': '{{ "now"|date("m") }}' })) }}
```

The problem I have is that the driver does not recognize the value of the variable, which corresponds to the current month (two digits). If I change `{ 'id': '{{ "now"|date("m") }}' }` for `{ 'id': '05' }` the controller already recognizes the variable and the result is obtained correctly, so the problem is how I can pass that value.

Comment: `... { 'id': ("now"|date("m")) } ...`

Comment: why are you quoting the variable? it should be just {{ render(controller("Bundle:Holidays:HolidaysPerMonth", { 'id': ' "now"|date("m") ' })) }}

Comment: You mean `{{ render(controller("Bundle:Holidays:HolidaysPerMonth", { 'id': "now"|date("m") })) }}`

Comment: It's like you comment, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you have given me, the solution is using the following expression for the variable:

```
 { 'id': ("now"|date("m")) }
```

Thank you very much